# Filter exceptions sent to Application insights from the client side

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am struggling with the problem that I'm getting a lot of the exceptions in Azure Application Insights with this error message: **Script error: The browser's same-origin policy prevents us from getting the details of this exception. Consider using the 'crossorigin' attribute.**

I understand that I need to add crossorigin="anonymous" to the script tag, but the problem is that these errors are generated from Ads script (which also loads other scripts) on our site, so I can't actually put that attribute for all of them.

Basically I don't even care about these errors, so I just don't want to send them to the
Application Insights at all. I've added the telementry initializer, which I expected will work to filter the errors, but I still receive a lot of that errors (~100.000 per day). Here is the initializer filtering I tried:

```
ai.addTelemetryInitializer((item) => {
    if (item.baseType == "ExceptionData" && item.baseData &&
        item.baseData.exceptions && item.baseData.exceptions.length > 0 && 
        item.baseData.exceptions[0].message.startsWith("Script error:")) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Also I've tried to filter it by item.baseData.error, but that also didn't help.

How should I configure the telemetry initializer so I can skip these errors?

Comment: Are you getting this error in F12 dev tools console? Or actually in Application Insights? My experience is that browsers don't expose details for any CORS-related errors. Instead it is just a plain failure without reasons. It might be tricky to filter such out.

Comment: @ZakiMa, no, I tried to replicate this locally or catch it in production in the dev tools console, but with no luck. I see the error only in the Application Insights exception logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sampling in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) to reduce/skip the errors.

- `<InitialSamplingPercentage>100</InitialSamplingPercentage>` : The amount of telemetry to sample when the app has just started.
- `<ExcludedTypes>Trace;Exception</ExcludedTypes>` : A semi-colon delimited list of types that you do not want to be subject to sampling. Recognized types are: Dependency, Event, Exception, PageView, Request, Trace.

You can refer to [How to exclude Exception and Error logging from sampling in Application Insights in .NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869747/how-to-exclude-exception-and-error-logging-from-sampling-in-application-insights), [Filter and preprocess telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor) and [No way to suppress cross-domain script errors from logging?](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1383)