# Azure App Insights - Script error: The browser's same-origin policy prevents us from getting the details of this exception

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have created an Angular application where I have integrated Azure App Insights. The problem is when I land on a specific page it logs the below error in app insights

`Script error: The browser's same-origin policy prevents us from getting the details of this exception. Consider using the 'crossorigin' attribute`

I have many users accessing the same page, but it occurs only to some users. I know we can solve it using `crossorigin` attribute but I want to know why it's occuring only for some users.

Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Comment: did you find the root cause of this

Answer (score -1):

To minimize or avoid the error, You can visit this   [MSFT doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) of Sampling in Application Insights.

- `<InitialSamplingPercentage>100</InitialSamplingPercentage>`  : When the app is first started, the amount of telemetry to sample.
- `<ExcludedTypes>Trace;Exception</ExcludedTypes>`  : A semi-colon delimited list of types that you don't wish to be subject to sampling. Dependency, Event, Exception, PageView, Request, and Trace are all recognised types.

**References :**

1. [No way to suppress cross-domain script errors from logging?](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/1383)
2. [How to exclude Exception and Error logging from sampling in Application Insights in .NET Core 2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869747/how-to-exclude-exception-and-error-logging-from-sampling-in-application-insights),
3. [Filter and preprocess telemetry in the Application Insights SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor)
4. [Case Study: Adding Application Insights to a website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/case-study-adding-application-insights-to-a-website/)

Comment: This doesn't really fix the underlying cause of the error, it just suppresses the logging of the error.